# Изменение CSS-свойства при изменении значения input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Код работает только при загрузке документа. Как сделать, чтобы код работал при изменении значения в `.search_field input`?

```
$(function() {
    if ($('.search_field').find('input').val()) {
        $('.button_field').find('input').css('background', '#bf1238 url(http://torawhite.ru/views/torawhite_ru/images/loop_white.svg) center no-repeat');
    } else {
        $('.button_field').find('input').css('background', '#aaaaaa url(http://torawhite.ru/views/torawhite_ru/images/loop_white.svg) center no-repeat');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Regent если убрать текст из поля, то скрипт не меняет обратно background

Comment: @Regent и при вводе в само текстовое поле текста тоже не добавляет. Добавляет только, если в html самостоятельно прописать текст в атрибуте value=""

Comment: @Regent вот это я и пытался выяснить, я не силён в js, почему так происходит понимал, но не мог найти нужный алгоритм. Спасибо!

Comment: За неимением нужного опыта корректная и понятная формулировка не всегда приходит в голову, к сожалению

Comment: Как говорится: "Правильно заданный вопрос содержит половину ответа".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет обработчика событий, поэтому процесс происходит только в момент готовности документа.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.search_field').find('input').on('keyup', switcher);
  switcher();
});
function switcher() {
  if ($('.search_field').find('input').val()) {
    $('.button_field').find('input').css('background', '#bf1238 url(http://torawhite.ru/views/torawhite_ru/images/loop_white.svg) center no-repeat');
  } else {
    $('.button_field').find('input').css('background', '#aaaaaa url(http://torawhite.ru/views/torawhite_ru/images/loop_white.svg) center no-repeat');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding : 7px;
}
.search_field > input{
   width : 230px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   height: 26px;
}
.button_field > input{
  width : 270px;
  padding: 0 150px 0px 0px;
  color : white;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_field">
  <input type="text" value="Значение при создании"/>
</div>
<div class="button_field">
  <input type="button" value="SEARCH" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, то, что нужно!

Comment: Переписал пример под разметку @Regent, она более точная

Comment: Кстати, можно `$('.search_field').find('input')` (и прочие подобные конструкции) заменить на `$('.search_field input')`. Код это делает короче, работает так же. Проще ли для восприятия - не знаю.

Comment: @Regent, была б моя воля, я бы так не написал вообще. Слишком низкий уровень абстракции, там же может быть чорт знает что.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать!

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov в длинном селекторе? Так ведь он тут не 100 символов - вполне видно что именно выбирается из документа.

Comment: @Torawhite, по идее, у вас должен быть некий фреймворк, который создает отображения, управляет DOM. В нем должны быть переопределены класы поведения элементов. Эти классы должны спрашивать у неких фабрик, как им себя вести в случае тех или иных данных и прочих ситуаций, возникающих в общей модели. JQuery позволяет это сделать, но возникает очень много ручной работы. Попробуйте Backbone + JQuery или AngularJS + JQuery. Из вопроса нам не видно, что и где происходит.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov спасибо! Но я так понимаю, это уже уровень гораздо выше, чем уровень новичка. Сделать всё идеально сразу редко получается, улучшения движка сайта и прочего приходят после запуска проекта, иначе его можно доводить до идеала всю жизнь. Возможно, ошибаюсь

Comment: @Torawhite, дык, кто ж его знает. Например, новички не собирают машины с нуля, отливая, штампуя и орабатывая детали. Они лезут в уже готовое. А Формулу-1 собирают и вовсе профессионалы высокого класса. Подход в получении навыка. Вот какой смысл иметь опыт сборки одноразового автомобиля, не имея представления о современных концепциях их разработки? Но вопрос, конечно, спорный. Я предпочитаю изучать чужие ошибки.